# What to do about unattached drywall corner?

Tags: drywall, framing

We purchased a medicine cabinet for a bathroom remodel and upon opening up the wall realized that there was a stud running through it in such a way as to make it impossible to put in the cabinet without having the door run into the wall next to it. Once the stud was cut, the corner of the drywall behind it was unsupported:

[image]

And the medicine cabinet niche was framed out like this:[image]

Is there a good way to support the now-floating corner of the drywall? The unsupported width is 14" and height is ~36".

Clarifications:

The medicine cabinet will be 16"x36" on the outside, or 35"x14.5". The new framed area in the photo is for supporting the medicine cabinet.

The length of unsupported drywall I'm concerned with is between my fingers:

[image]

Comment: More detail needed.  How wide is the new medicine cabinet that you're trying to install?  And how are you going to support the new medicine cabinet?  You have to have proper framing for that as well.  Are you sure you have enough room for this in that space?

Comment: I've added the answers to this to the body of the question.

Comment: How tight (sides, not top/bottom) is the cabinet fit in that opening?

Comment: The fit of the sides is quite tight, maybe a quarter inch.

Comment: This might be a dumb idea, but I was thinking you could use a few corner brace/angle brackets inside the space that would mount to the stud and sit against, but not attach to the drywall. This should prevent the drywall from being pushed in from the other side. I'm not leaving that as an answer because I'd have to think someone here has a better idea.

Comment: Also, won't the medicine cabinet be snug up against it?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, there should be about a quarter inch between the back of the medicine cabinet and the drywall behind it.